# Mobile number regex not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

I wrote a simple regex to match mobile numbers for the following conditions:

- Optionally beginning with +91 or 0
- Followed by 9, 8, or 7.
- Followed by nine digits

Here's what I tried:

```
/^((\+91)|0)?[987]\d{9}$/
```

This works in almost all the cases, but it's flagging mobile numbers like `09811325760` as wrong. Why is this?

```
echo preg_match('/^((\+91)|0)?[987]\d{9}$/', 09811325760);
0
```

Comment: ¯\_ツ_/¯ Your number: `09811325760` is interpreted as an octal number, you want a string here, since you have 0 in front of your number.

Comment: You probably need to pass the number as a string, as PHP does not have preceding 0s for any number type. `0981` might become `981`.

Comment: Arrrrgh! Thanks, guys. :-)

Comment: @dotslash That's a bit of a tricky one to figure out. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php as reference for that: *octal       : 0[0-7]+*

Comment: Due to the leading 0 the number should indeed be interpreted as octal. Doesn't this throw an error due to invalid numeric literal? 8 and 9 are not valid digits in octal.

Comment: @Filkolev PHP 7 yes, lower versions they just get cut off and you end up with a question here :)

Comment: @Rizier123 I knew leading 0 can be treated as octal. Just didn't strike me when testing this. Silly me! :P

Comment: @Rizier123 By the way, how do you enter that stick-figure smiley in comments? :D

Comment: @dotslash Just copied it from somewhere.

Comment: ¯_ツ_/¯  Ah! Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to answer your question here, your number is due to the leading 0 interpreted as octal number: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

(Also: Since 8 and 9 are invalid octal numbers your number also gets cut off there)

So you have to use your number as string in your code, e.g.

```
echo preg_match('/^((\+91)|0)?[987]\d{9}$/', "09811325760");
```

In PHP 7 this behaviour also was changed: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.integers.invalid-octals and now you get a syntax error for it, so you don't have to ask a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

See he code below it will support lot more formats like support of -, . as separator along with your problem

`((\+91)|0)?[987]\d{2}[-.]?\d{3}[-.]?\d{4}\b`

Comment: Hey, thanks! For now my requirement was very specific, but I'll keep this in mind.